# Gazebo model interaction without ros

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I just started to learn gazebo. I want to control my model from keyboard. There is a turtlesim example for ros,but Is it possible to take key events from gazebo without using ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6460/gazebo-model-interaction-without-ros/) by [Ahmet Özkul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/864/ahmet-%C3%B6zkul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
Thanks for the suggestions. Finally, I achieved controlling model from the keyboard. I used http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim example code. I took turtlesim, terminal reading part and added it to update function of my model. In every update, it checks if there is a key press. update function of my code is below.

```
 // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate()
    {
          char c;
        int kfd = 0;
    struct termios cooked, raw;
          // get the console in raw mode                                                              
      tcgetattr(kfd, &cooked);
      memcpy(&raw, &cooked, sizeof(struct termios));
      raw.c_lflag &=~ (ICANON | ECHO);
      // Setting a new line, then end of file                         
      raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;
      raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
      tcsetattr(kfd, TCSANOW, &raw);
        struct pollfd pfd = {0,0,0};       /* poll() settings   */
      int pr;                            /* poll() result     */
      
      pfd.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
      pfd.events = POLLIN;
      pr = poll(&pfd, 1, 100);
      if(pr>0)
      {
        if(read(kfd, &c, 1) < 0)
        {
          perror("read():");
          exit(-1);
        }
        double rad = 1;
            switch(c)
            {
              case KEYCODE_L:
                puts("LEFT");
                this->left_wheel_joint_->SetAngle(0,0);  //joint
                break;
              case KEYCODE_D:
                puts("DOWN");
                this->left_wheel_joint_->SetAngle(0,-rad); //joint
                break;
            }
       }
       else{
        //no key
        }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Ahmet Özkul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/864/ahmet-%C3%B6zkul/) with karma: 1 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0